# creating a class with two string fields that concatenate in a method, and a method to prints the result

Tags: python

this has to be more simple than it seems.

```py
class stringjoiner:
    stri_one = "I am "
    stri_two = "really struggling with this"
    def joiner(str, str):
        self.stri_one = stri_one
        self.stri_two = stri_two
        result = join(stri_one + stri_two)
        
    def printer():
        print(result)

stringjoiner.printer()
```

I'm such a noob, i can't even get stack to display my code properly. this is my first post here.

so i can't access the strings directly to concatenate them.

what am I doing wrong?

edit:

my code now reads:
"""
class stringJoiner:

```
def __init__(self, stri_one:str, stri_two:str):
    stri_one = "I am "
    stri_two = "really struggling with this"
    self.stri_one = stri_one
    self.stri_two = stri_two
    result = join(stri_one + stri_two)
    return result

def printer(self):
    print(result)
```

"""

i get that in the second method, result has the red squigglies because its a variable that is local to the previous method... no? so how do i make this thing print two concatenated strings without directly accessing the strings like join("this is a" + " string") ?

Comment: Being new is not an excuse, there is a preview functionality. Now several things are to be said : 1) you can initialise your class with a `__init__` method which can automatically define attributes when you're creating a new instance of that class. 2) each method must have `self` as an argument. 3) Variables created inside the definition of a function are "local" and will not exist in other functions (`result`). 4) Even though you wrote a `joiner` method, you never call it. 5) a class is callable so you have to use parentheses when defining it

Comment: What is the purpose of using a class here? Is this homework? Does the homework specify that the string fields should be class variables and the joiner method should be a static method? Or should the string fields be instance variables? It's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Where is the `join` function defined? Why do you concatenate the strings with `+` but then pass that value into a function called `join`?

Comment: i saw what it looked like, when i put tripple quotes it didn't turn it to code, or maybe i screwed that up too. i really don't know what i did wrong. as for the code, i cannot directly access the strings.

the code reads: 
"""class stringJoiner:

    def __init__(self, stri_one:str, stri_two:str):
        stri_one = "I am "
        stri_two = "really struggling with this"
        self.stri_one = stri_one
        self.stri_two = stri_two
        self.joiner(stri_one + stri_two)
        result = 
        return result
    def printer(self):
        print(result)"""

Comment: ddejohn, thanks, removing that function join() got rid of some of my issues up there, now i'm just stuck with figuring out how to make it actually print that result in the previous method

and yes, this is a practice question that i'm struggling with. 
they did not specify, but i know that 'result' is static or local to the first method so i don't know how to properly print result in a seperate method.  i have to create a class that has two strings and two mehtods - one method that joins the strings and one method that prints the resulting concat/join

Answer (score 1):

if you want to join two defined strings then just simpley

```
def joiner(stri_one,stri_two):
    stri_three = stri_one + stri_two
    return stri_three
```

if you want have words of a sentence in a list then you can use

```
text = ["there", "is" ,"a" ,"programmer"]
print(" ".join(text))
```

this is going to join the words in the list by putting a space between them.

Comment: i think the `self` arguments in the first functions are a mistake

Comment: my second function has to be one that prints that stri_three to the actual terminal, and i'm stuck there because its local to the pervious method

Comment: please elaborate